# Troubleshooting Android ADT installation 

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Eclipse Gallieo. While installing the ADT plugin, following error comes up:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You should accept the answer if you found a valuable suggestion which helped you fix your problem... This would help you in turn to improve your accept ratio, and even help others who may face a similar issue in the future!

Answer (score 1):

ADT 16 supports eclipse 3.7 java
i am using eclipse 3.7 and install ADT 16.0.1 its install properly and it now working..

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6) or higher is required for ADT 16.0.1.
You must install a newer version of Eclipse such as Helios or Indigo.